# running jelly bean 4.1.1 on Galaxy note screen flashes when I retrieve voice mail

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

running jelly bean 4.1.1 on Galaxy S111 Note, the input screen flashes when I retrieve voice mail so bad, you can't input password.